# Объяснение статьи

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты, роутинг

Изучаю https://habr.com/ru/companies/agima/articles/584130/. Не минусуйте - материал сложный.

1. В статье указано

> Для вывода контента страниц в общем случае используется компонент и его шаблон как основа визуальной части. **Роутинг начинается от корня раздела, где находится компонент.** Компонент может быть простым и комплексным, т. е. отдает контент одной страницы либо различных в зависимости от параметра в URL.

Что такое роутинг в bitrix? Bitrix ведь не Laravel. Я нашел https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=013764, но статья написана не для последней версии bitrix, а для всех версий.

2. В статье используется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Про какие компоненты идет речь (приведите ссылки)? Я пытался искать - https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82+%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0+bitrix&newwindow=1&sca_esv=576737612&sxsrf=AM9HkKmP7lYcEU8z-FQnTXaxPdsqp4QKsA%3A1698298862497&source=hp&ei=7vs5Ze2dHICGwPAP7cGLmAw&iflsig=AO6bgOgAAAAAZToJ_oTxbZu_jeM-z0GnQoQz9MQ1XYF3&oq=%D0%BA%D0%BE&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IgTQutC-KgIIADIEECMYJzILEAAYigUYsQMYgwEyCxAAGIAEGLEDGIMBMhEQLhiABBixAxiDARjHARjRAzIIEAAYgAQYsQMyBRAAGIAEMgsQABiABBixAxiDATILEAAYgAQYsQMYgwEyCBAuGIAEGLEDMgsQABiABBixAxiDAUjUDlAAWLYCcAB4AJABAJgBUqABogGqAQEyuAEByAEA-AEBwgILEC4YgAQYsQMYgwHCAgUQLhiABMICCxAuGIoFGLEDGIMB&sclient=gws-wiz, не нашел.

3. Также в статье указаны (на рисунке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что имеется ввиду под компонентами (список, детальная) Vue приложения?

Я новичок, прошу не минусовать.

Comment: Разве не проще попробовать получить ответы из первых рук?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: _Что такое роутинг в bitrix? Bitrix ведь не Laravel._ - а что такое роутинг в Laravel?

Comment: @Grundy роутинг в Laravel - это Route:get(...) в web.php

Comment: а что делает этот метод?

Comment: @Grundy - https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing

Comment: @vladdv, у битрикса есть точно такая же страничка со справкой: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=013764

Comment: Все то же самое - способ сопоставить `url` в браузере конкретную страницу

Answer (score 0):

1. В битриксе имеется специальный механизм роутинга - через файл urlrewrite.php, в котором прописываются правила подмены страниц в случае, если их физически нет на сайте. Битриксовские компоненты этим механизмом активно пользуются. Например, в параметрах инфоблока или в параметрах компонента можно указать URL для разделов или для детального просмотра. Комплексные компоненты при этом будут подставлять свои подкомпоненты.
2. Скорее всего, здесь имеется в виду комплексный компонент catalog и простые компоненты catalog.section и catalog.element. Папок /section/ и /section/detail/ на сайте физически не существует, вместо них управление передаётся в корень, а уж там комплексный компонент решает, какой из подкомпонентов показать.
3. А здесь авторы показывают общую структуру своего Vue-приложения. Они для каждого компонента битрикс строят шаблон. В каждом шаблоне его рендерингом занимется своё Vue-приложение, которое тоже использует свои строительные блоки - vue-компоненты. И соответственно vue-компонент "список" служит для отображения компонента catalog.section, а vue-компонент "детальный" - для отображения компонента  catalog.element.